# set dynamic 'initialRouteName' in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

question is simple I know there are lots of answers available for the same question but I have differently set my own `App.js` file i tried almost all but no success.

so my `App.js` looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';
import { Header, Button, Spinner } from './src/components/comman';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import LoginForm from './src/components/LoginForm';
import SignupForm from './src/components/SignupForm';
import Home from './src/components/Home';
import ForgetPassword from './src/components/ForgetPassword';


import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
const App = createStackNavigator ({
  Login: { screen: LoginForm },
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Signup: { screen: SignupForm },
  ForgetPassword: { screen : ForgetPassword },
  },
  { 
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
  });

export default App;
```

Now I store login state in `AsyncStorage` in my `LoginForm.js` like this

```
.
.
AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true').then((a) => {
    this.onLoginSuccess(responseData.user_id);
});
.
.
```

so now i want to set `initialRouteName` based on my local storage element.
Simple if `isLoggedIn` is `true` then `initialRouteName : Home` otherwise `initialRouteName : Login`

Simple but don't how to use this in `my` `App.js`

Please help :)

Comment: Instead of doing this if and else use redirect. Even I faced a lot of issue and finally went with the redirect method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/458#issuecomment-370961489):

> If you need to set the initialRouteName as a prop it is because there is some data that you need to fetch asynchronously before you render the app navigation. another way to handle this is to use a switchnavigator and have a screen that you show when you are fetching the async data, then navigate to the appropriate initial route with params when necessary. see [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html) for a full example of this.

And this is an open [RFC](https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/23)

### UPDATE

Take a look at [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html).

You'll find more description!

Comment: Thanks for answer buddy but can u please write code ? I am new in react-native so don't know that much basics :)

Comment: take a loop at [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) - you can find a full description!

Answer (score 4):

You can write like this

```
 <Stack.Navigator
  {...{initialRouteName: isLoggedIn ? 'Home' : 'Login'}}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```